# exec function is not executing and is not raising error (python)

Tags: python, built-in

I'm a beginner programmer and I am trying to understand the difference between these three functions. Originally my problem is a bit different but I made it this easy for not to take your time a lot. I actually learned exec function today and no matter how much I try different variations with the function, I can't understand the difference between these v1 and v2. I want to use the v1 version but it doesn't change the variable p5. If anyone can clarify me I would be so glad.

NOTE: Original problem have p1,p2,p3,...,p9 and I get the index from the user input. So it is important to formatting string.

```
p5 = 5
index_of_p = 5


def change_p5_v1():
    exec(f"global p{index_of_p}")
    exec(f"p{index_of_p} = 3")
    print(p5)  # Output 5


def change_p5_v2():
    exec("global p5")
    exec("p5 = 3")
    print(p5)  # Output 5


def change_p5_v3():
    global p5
    p5 = 3
    print(p5)  # Output 3


change_p5_v1()
change_p5_v2()
change_p5_v3()
```

Comment: If you are a beginner, you should not be using `exec`.  Period.  Almost always, there is a faster, simpler, and safer way of achieving what you want.

Comment: I think I have exceeded my limits accidentally. Looking forward to learn the background of it. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the namespace you want to update in your `exec` call:

```
def change_p5_v1():
    exec(f"p{index_of_p} = 3", globals())
    print(p5)  # Output 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec()`s run one after the other are entirely separate; the first `exec("global ...")` doesn't affect the next `exec()`.

Anyway, you should **never use `eval()` or `exec()`** unless you have some *very* specific need, and as a beginner, you, well, don't.

What you seem to be doing with `p{index_of_p}` is basically a dict, or
["variable variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) - and since you're not assigning into `p`, you don't need `global` either.

```
p = {0: 0, 1: 10}
index = 0

def change_p():
    p[index] += 1

print(p)
change_p()
print(p)
change_p()
print(p)
index = 1
change_p()
print(p)
```

Comment: That's a wonderful suggestion. I'm a mathematics teacher because of that im used to say p1,p2.. etc. as an index. What you are saying to me is instead of doing that, create a dict, and instead of using p1, just use p[1]. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes - or a list. May be worth it to reread python.org's tutorial regarding these data types.